# Default parameter value obtained by invoking another instance method

Tags: python, default

The following code works for providing a meaningful default value for `conns`  but it is quite ugly:

```
def query(s,sql,conns=None):
  conns = s.conns() if not conns else conns
```

A preferred construct would be:

```
def query(s,sql,conns=s.conns()):
```

But that is apparently disallowed: I am inferring that instance method invocations are not supported within invocations of other methods on the same instance.

Is there a cleaner pattern for supplying the default/missing parameter?

Comment: Just use `if conns is None: conns = s.conns()`, you don't need the conditional expression. It's not that it's "not supported", exactly, but think about when the default value is evaluated - the class isn't fully defined, let alone an instance created.

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8131942/3001761

Comment: The construct you show of course I considered but it is effectively 2 lines after proper formatting: it's noise. Well I guess there really is not a better pattern.