# Optional arguments in class methods

Tags: python-3.x, optional-parameters

I have a class function where if optional parameter(yaml file) is passed then read the values and pass it as optional parameters to the def books() function. But executing the below code, I get error as 'name 'self' is not defined. How can I read the yaml items into the books function as an optional parameter?

```
class Price:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if args:
            with open(args, 'r') as f:
                stream = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
            bookname= stream['book']['name']
            self.param = bookname
        else:
            self.param = None
        return self.param 

    def books(self, file, name=self.param):
         print(file,name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a default argument value of an instance member to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131942/how-to-pass-a-default-argument-value-of-an-instance-member-to-a-method)

Answer (score 3):

This error seems to occur because of the `.books()` method, not the optional arguments. You cannot refer to `self.param` in the method signature. Instead, you need to access this attribute within the method. For example, based on your requirements, you could rewrite it as such:

```py
def books(self, file, name=None):
    name_to_print = name or self.param # take the name if provided or the self.param
    print(file, name_to_print)
```

Finally, another issue you'll come across is that the class constructor (`__init__()`) shouldn't be returning `self.param`, but `None` (i.e. it shouldn't be returning anything). The moment you set `self.param` above, it becomes an attribute of the class instance and you don't need to return it. So, I would remove the row `return self.param`.

Comment: Thank you and it works. I kept the return statement in init method assuming that the error was related to it. But now get the point thanks

Comment: @sinG20 glad it helped